# setEnabled for UISegmentedControl without styling differently

Tags: swift, uisegmentedcontrol, appearance

I am using Swift 4, and I'd like to disable a `UISegmentedControl` during a demonstration, but I do not want it to style it differently while this is happening. For instance, my `UISegmentedControl` is called `saveAsControl`, and I disable a segment:

```
self.saveAsControl.setEnabled(false, forSegmentAt: 0)
```

But when this happens, I do not want it to change the appearance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an extension. Alternatively, you could solve this problem using a simple one-liner which sets the text color of your disabled segments to the default `tintColor` of the `segmentedControl`:

```
let segmentItems = ["one", "two", "three"]
let mySegmentedControl = UISegmentedControl(items: segmentItems)

UISegmentedControl.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor:mySegmentedControl.tintColor], for: .disabled)

mySegmentedControl.setEnabled(false, forSegmentAt: 0)
```

Make sure that you are using `UISegmentedControl` instead of `mySegmentedControl` since `appearance()` is a static method of the `UISegmentedControl` class.

This is a screenshot of my code when I run it in the playground:
[image]

Comment: I have not got this to work correctly. It immediately makes my text grey instead of black. I tried setting this before and after the control gets disabled, but I don't think it should matter anyway.

Comment: Yup, I am using UISegmentedControl instead of mySegmentedControl. Looks like it is being caused by the extra appearance changes I made to it. Just a note, I did try looking through the keys for NSAttributedString, but I didn't see anything obvious for the text color.

Comment: Nope, it still turns the text gray.

Comment: It seems way more complicated than it should be, but I can see how your method could work and help a lot of people. Thank you. I marked your answer as correct. I ended up using a transparent UIView to temporarily block the active controls.

Comment: Alright, glad you could solve the problem. I am also confident that my answer has the potential to help many others in a similar situation as yours. I will be deleting my other comments shortly to avoid a lengthy discussion for whoever stumbles upon this question. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

```
extension UISegmentedControl {
    func setUserInteractionEnabled(_ enabled: Bool, forSegmentAt segment: Int) {
        if subviews.indices.contains(segment) {
            subviews[segment].isUserInteractionEnabled = enabled
        }
    }
}

segmentedControl.setUserInteractionEnabled(false, forSegmentAt: 0)
```